# Is it possible to iterate a mongo cursor twice?

Tags: mongodb

In other words, is there a way to rewind it to the beginning?

**EDIT**

I am using mongo shell and pymongo.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [Ruby API](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html#rewind%21-instance_method) has the `rewind!` method that does exactly what you want.

The [Python API](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) also has the `cursor.rewind()` method.

The [PHP API](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.rewind.php) also has the `cursor.rewind()` method.

However, neither the Java or C++ APIs have the rewind method. All can be found from the [official API page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Online+API+Documentation).

Comment: Good to know, but I am not using Ruby.

Comment: I dont know either of those two APIs but I wonder if they are both just driver tricks - Is this something that is supported by MongoDB natively

Comment: As per the docs and the [code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py) the database does not support this natively, and a new query will be sent to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Cursor in pymongo has `.rewind()` method, you can refer to [sample code from previous question with answer that apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789601/pymongo-doesnt-iterate-over-collection/9790057#9790057).

Native mongo shell api, however, doesn't provide such method, see [method `help()` on DBQuery object prototype.](http://api.mongodb.org/js/current/symbols/src/shell_query.js.html):

```
> db.collection.find().help()
find() modifiers
        .sort( {...} )
        .limit( n )
        .skip( n )
        .count() - total # of objects matching query, ignores skip,limit
        .size() - total # of objects cursor would return, honors skip,limit
        .explain([verbose])
        .hint(...)
        .showDiskLoc() - adds a $diskLoc field to each returned object

Cursor methods
        .forEach( func )
        .map( func )
        .hasNext()
        .next()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cursor.reset();`

For PHP : `$cursor->reset();`

then run your `foreach($cursorData as $data)` any time after resetting.