# Iterating over Mongo Cursors more than once using ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Just started playing with MongoDB.

```
irb(main):037:0> @db.insert({"color" => "Blue"})
=> BSON::ObjectId('4f7aaf3a1d41c81634000002')
```

Now I try to use the find method, after using find_one:

```
irb(main):039:0> @results = @db.find({"color" => "Blue"})
=> <Mongo::Cursor:0x4340c48 namespace='tutorial.users' @selector={"color"=>"Blue"} @cursor_id=>
```

Now I try to iterate of the results:

```
irb(main):040:0> @results.each do |aa|
irb(main):041:1* puts aa["color"]
irb(main):042:1> end
Blue
=> nil
```

**When I run it again, nothing shows up**

```
irb(main):043:0> @results.each do |aa|
irb(main):044:1* puts aa["color"]
irb(main):045:1> end
=> nil
```

[Is it possible to iterate a mongo cursor twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872891/is-it-possible-to-iterate-a-mongo-cursor-twice)

The post above says, that I must use the rewind! method in ruby class.

Lets see:

```
irb(main):046:0> @results.rewind!
=> true
irb(main):047:0> @results.each do |aa|
irb(main):048:1* puts aa["color"]
irb(main):049:1> end
Blue
=> nil
```

**Why is the cursor only good for one run?**

If I was building a rails app using the ruby driver direct, and tried pagination, the second someone hit a back button, nothing would work.

There are other options, but it seems like a hack.

I read somewhere on a 10 minute limit, but this seems to be good for one use only?

**What is happening here, and why can't I iterate over it again, atleast under the 10 minute server limit?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over a cursor again means sending the query to MongoDB again. The cursor doesn't not store all of the query results locally. That would be very inefficient, and could result in inaccuracies (e.g., not reflecting the latest writes).

Typically with pagination, you issue a separate query (or new cursor) for each page you want to display, using skip and limit. There's nothing hackish about that. In any case, a cursor object won't persist between requests, so you must create a brand new cursor each time anyway.

Comment: I see. I am reading the documentation, and api docs in best trying to understand the whole picture. Now, so I have to manually add in a limit and skip statements to my cursor objects?

Somewhere I read that "next" might help in trying to do pagination.

Also, do I have to use something like MongoMapper/Mongoid to create a rails app. I just wanted to see how far I could get in using simply the ruby driver since it seems more "simple".