# Can we reset cursor in mongodb to true?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
// Inserting three documents into collection named "foo"
db.getCollection("foo").insertMany([
{"name" : "abc" , "age" : 29}, 
{"name" : "pqm" ,"age" :32},
{"name" : "xyz" , "age" : 33}])

// cursor
var cursor = db.getCollection("foo").find()

// You can use the cursor method forEach() to iterate the cursor and
access the documents
cursor.forNext()

// next() method is used to point the cursor to next document
cursor.next()
```

After using cursor.next() 3 times, can we again reset cursor to 0?

Comment: Assuming that your question is how to "reset" the cursor, this is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872891/is-it-possible-to-iterate-a-mongo-cursor-twice

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is cursor `rewind()` method.

**Try using :**

```
cursor.rewind()
```

From official MongoDB documentation :

> **rewind**
>
> Resets this cursor to its initial state. All settings like the query string, tailable, batchSizeValue, skipValue and limits are
>   preserved.
>
> rewind()
>
> ```
>  Returns: cursor returns itself with rewind applied.
> ```

Check [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#rewind) for more information on `cursor.rewind()`

Comment: After using the command I am getting this error: 

> cursor.rewind()
2018-07-14T21:16:54.082+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: cursor.rewind is not a function :
@(shell):1:1

Comment: I have added the exact codes above in the question.

Comment: I am asking you to show, how you are using `cursor.rewind()`

Answer (score 0):

There's a `close()` method you can use on the current query.

```js
db.collection.find(<query>).close()
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.close/#cursor.close